# How to access "Configure" page to set up bridge relay

Tags: relays, bridge

I downloaded the latest Tor version and now need to configure a bridge relay, as the web site I am trying to view is still banning me (www.godlikeproductions.com). They must have very sophisticated IP identification software. How do I go to the "Configure" page since the Tor browser is now loaded?

Answer (score 2):

If a site is banning 'you' (they actually ban all Tor exit nodes) then using bridges will not help you.

Bridges are an alternative way to *enter* the Tor network, which can be useful if *your* ISP blocks you from connecting to a normal Tor guard relay.
Regardless of whether you use a bridge or not, you still *exit* the network through the same exit nodes.

In order to visit that site, you can look for a different VPN or proxy service, one that they haven't banned.

---

(Edit to add, to answer the actual question..)

To setup bridges,

- Click on the Tor Button,
- Select 'Tor Network Settings',
- Check 'My Internet Service Provider (ISP) blocks connections to the Tor network'.